# Deriving hash of a file from hashes of pieces of that file

Tags: algorithm, hash, sha

I have a file say foo.txt. Say, it's SHA-256 is SHA(foo.txt). Now, I divide the file into multiple pieces say p1, p2, ... pn. Hashes of each of these pieces is SHA(p1), SHA(p2), ... SHA(pn).

My question is, Is it possible in some way to derive SHA(foo.txt), given only SHA(p1), SHA(p2), ..., SHA(pn)?

I am working on a problem where I have hashes of each of the pieces of a file. But, I need to derive SHA of the actual file without having access to at any of the pieces or the actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is impossible. It would go against the nature of a *secure* hash function.

The only thing you can do is store the hashes of *all* the pieces (along with information how long they are), and then check the "combined" hash by checking all the corresponding pieces of the complete file in the same manner.

Comment: That's not the _only_ thing he can do - depending on his needs, a merkle tree might be useful.